# 550 5.7.1 This message does not comply with required standards

Tags: email, smtp

We have never had this problem before but recently some recipients of our service started receiving no emails.

After trying to forward intended email from another box successfully received this letter without problems, we get this response:

**550 5.7.1 This message does not comply with required standards.**

Moreover this message can be found in the SMTP logs enabled for our service. Seems there is no other useful information in the logs.

This is very strange because same email can be delivered to other recipients just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DSN 5.7.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1893.txt) means the message is not allowed to be delivered--often because it is believed to be spam, or contain a virus, but it could be other things as well.

There's really no way to know why the message was rejected without consulting the logs of the server that issued the rejection.

Comment: Thanks Flimzy! this RFC was exactly what I needed.